# Радио кнопки отображаются в Safari как чекбоксы

Tags: css, input, safari

Есть форма, в которой имеются радио кнопки. Эти радио кнопки на мобильном сафари отображаются как чекбоксы (а выбранные радио кнопки отображаются как маленькие и не выбранные) (см. скриншот).

Единственное, что нашёл в интернете это свойство `-webkit-appearance: radio`, но оно никак не помогло

Как я понял, сам сафари переопределяет стили этих кнопок на свои, вопрос в том как их отключить или переопределить на нормальные?

UPD: пример кнопки

```
<input type="radio" name="customer" value="1" checked="checked">
```

Стилей почти никакх нет, кроме высоты/ширины и позиционирования
[image: Safari checkbox]

Comment: Может это поможет  -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: Так кнопки просто пропадают

Comment: добавьте код кнопок в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Сперва нужно обнулит стили:

```
input, textarea, button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    resize: none;
}
```

А после мы задаем новые:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
}
```

Comment: зачем обнулять `textarea` и `button`?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko чтобы каждый раз не обнулять при написании кнопкок и полей. Но это женский вариант. Правильней будет не все input обнулять. Посмотрите, как мы делали здесь https://github.com/1000tech/godlike.css

Comment: я имею в виду, что `textarea` и `button` не имеют отношения к `input[type="radio"]`, о котором спрашивают, зачем тогда их обнулять в данном конкретном сниппете кода? во-вторых, зачем вначале обнулять радиокнопку при помощи `-webkit-appearance: none`, а потом задавать ей `-webkit-appearance: radio`? почему не сразу задать ей определение?